# "Element is not clickable" error in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have been using the same scripts for over a year, but since yesterday i am getting this error when click on links having images. I am getting the element by xpath and then clicking it.

```
test_101_HomePage_links (__main__.SprintTests) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_101_HomePage_links (__main__.SprintTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Zaakpay\website\sanity results\debug\tests.py", line 17, in test_101_HomePage_links
    a.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 73, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 456, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (281.25, 61). Other element would receive the click: <span></span>


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 23.062s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Other info:
using windows,
using python,
using firefox,
same script was working fine till yesterday

My code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import time

class SprintTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://www.zaakpay.com")

    def test_101_HomePage_links(self):
        a= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/a/i")
        a.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        a = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="view1"]/p')
        b=a.text
        self.assertEqual('-Payment Gateway Services.\n-More than you want payment options with.\n-major credit cards, debit cards and 52 netbanking banks.\n-Fastest Merchant Approval.\n-Smooth integration across 22 platforms.\n-Start in minutes.\n-Multi-Currency Processing Service with 13 currencies.\n\nSIGN UP',b )


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

link i am trying to click is circular image above text- WEBSITE PAYMENT GATEWAY

Comment: take a screen shot just after when this exception is thrown and include it in your question. Something is blocking your click

Comment: which element got this click instead? can you tell? I have had this error before, the element you wanted to click might have been masked or invisible.

Comment: driver.save_screenshot("path to save \\screen.jpeg")

Comment: I have added the code, you all can reproduce the issue now.

Comment: There is no issue coming up with the above code with Chrome as driver. Also, you could simply use `a= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="#view1"]')` instead of `a= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/a/i")` right! It's hard to debug with the latter.

Comment: @praba..i need to use firefox only...can you help with that

Comment: did you check to see if there was a change in the behavior of the product?  Perhaps there is a new message that appears, which is blocking your target element.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware: no, no change. Also, i have provided the webpage and link to click. Please see, if you can click it.

Answer (score 1):

Using XPATHs like this `/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/a/i` are problematic for a number of reasons.

First and foremost, they are extremely brittle. All it takes is a minor update to the site, one that might night even be visually perceptible, and the hard coded div indexes break. The site devs might have added a div to slightly alter a font style and then your XPATH is completely broken.

Second, it makes it next to impossible to debug once it does break. I have absolutely no idea what you were intending to click on, and if this were production code that someone else was attempting to fix, they would also have no idea what you were intending to click on.

My best guess is that zaakpay made some small, imperceptible change that slightly changed the location of your target element in the DOM. If you update the XPATH to something like `//div[@class=\"prdtBlck\"]/ul/li/a`, as I've done below, your script works:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import time

class SprintTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://www.zaakpay.com")

    def test_101_HomePage_links(self):
        a=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class=\"prdtBlck\"]/ul/li/a")
        a.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        a = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="view1"]/p')
        b=a.text
        self.assertEqual('-Payment Gateway Services.\n-More than you want payment options with.\n-major credit cards, debit cards and 52 netbanking banks.\n-Fastest Merchant Approval.\n-Smooth integration across 22 platforms.\n-Start in minutes.\n-Multi-Currency Processing Service with 13 currencies.\n\nSIGN UP',b )


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: I agree with pretty much everything that you stated but I would suggest that you instead use a CSS Selector, "a[href='#view1']". That will get you exactly the element that OP is looking for with no relative references.

Comment: I agree, that would be a better path.

Comment: There is no change in xpath, you may cross check with xpath of my code and of the webpage. I have 100s of such links in my code and all of them started giving error suddenly. It is a hard task to rewrite all xpath again. Anyways, seems thats the only option.